# Make the numbers 1-100 using 1,7,3,4

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

I made this puzzle myself. As the title says, you must make the numbers 1 to 100 using the numbers 1,7,3,4 - in that order. All numbers must be used. The allowed operators are below:

- Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication and Division.
- Square roots and exponents.
- Factorials.
- Concatenation.
- Floor and Ceiling Functions.
- Parentheses.

Anything that is not on this list must NOT be used.

Those are all the rules, Have fun!

Comment: Allowed as part of a solution: non integer factorals? (e.g.  sqrt(24)! = 4.898! = 101.096)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It required some cups of coffee, and it became quite messy for some specific numbers, but hopefully the below solution is without errors and typos. Looking forward to seeing better (read "easier") solutions to these numbers where possible.

> $1:  1^{734}$
>  $2:  1^7-3+4$
>  $3:  1-\text{floor}(7/3)+4$
>  $4:  -1-7+3*4$
>  $5:  -1*7+3*4$
>  $6:  1*7+3-4$
>  $7:  1+7+3-4$
>  $8:  1^7+3+4$ 
>  $9:  1+7-3+4$
>  $10: 1^7+3^{√4}$
>  $11: -1^7+3*4$
>  $12: \text{floor}(1/7)+3*4$
>  $13: 1^7+3*4$
>  $14: 1*7+3+4$
>  $15: 1+7+3+4$
>  $16: -1+7*3-4$
>  $17: 1*7*3-4$
>  $18: 1+7*3-4$
>  $19: 1*7+3*4$
>  $20: 1+7+3*4$
>  $21: 1+(7+3)*√4$
>  $22: -1+7*3+√4$
>  $23: 1*7*3+√4$
>  $24: 1+7*3+√4$
>  $25: 1*7*3+4$
>  $26: 1+7*3+4$
>  $27: 1*\text{floor}(\sqrt{734})$
>  $28: (1+7)*3+4$
>  $29: 1*(\text{ceil}(√7))^3+√4$
>  $30: 1+(\text{ceil}(√7))^3+√4$
>  $31: 1*(\text{ceil}(√7))^3+4$
>  $32: 1+(\text{ceil}(√7))^3+4$
>  $33: -1^7+34$
>  $34: \text{floor}(1/7)+34$
>  $35: 1^7+34$
>  $36: 17*\text{ceil}(√3)+√4$
>  $37: 1*\text{ceil}(√7)+34$
>  $38: 1+\text{ceil}(√7)+34$
>  $39: \text{ceil}(√17)+34$
>  $40: -1+7+34$
>  $41: 1*7+34$
>  $42: 1+7+34$
>  $43: 1+7*\text{ceil}(√34)$
>  $44: -1+7^{\text{ceil}(√3)} -4$
>  $45: 1*7^{\text{ceil}(√3)} -4$
>  $46: 1+7^{\text{ceil}(√3)} -4$
>  $47: 17*3-4$
>  $48: 1+7^{\text{ceil}(√3)}-√4$
>  $49: 17*3-√4$\
>  $50: -1+7^{\text{ceil}(√3)} +√4$
>  $51: 17+34\\ 52: 1+7^{\text{ceil}(√3)} +√4$
>  $53: 1*7^{\text{ceil}(√3)} +4$
>  $54: (-1+7)^3/4 $
>  $55: -1+\text{ceil}(\sqrt(7!/√3)   )+√4   $
>  $56: -1+\text{ceil}(\sqrt(7!/√3)   )+√4$
>  $57: -1+\text{floor}(7^{√3}*√4)$
>  $58: \text{floor}(17*√(3*4))$
>  $59: \text{ceil}(17*√(3*4))$
>  $60: (1+\text{ceil}(√7))^3-4$
>  $61: 1*\text{ceil}(√(7!*3)/√4)$
>  $62: (1+\text{ceil}(√7))^3-√4$
>  $63: \text{ceil}(√17 !)+34$
>  $64: -17+3^4$
>  $65: \text{floor}(√((1+7)!)/3-√4)$
>  $66: \text{floor}(√(17^3 ))-4$
>  $67: -1+\text{floor}(√7)*34$
>  $68: -1+73-4$
>  $69: 1*73-4$
>  $70: -1+73-√4$
>  $71: 1*73-√4$
>  $72: 1+73-√4$
>  $73: -1-7+3^4$
>  $74: -1*7+3^4$
>  $75: 1-7+3^4$
>  $76: -1+73+4$
>  $77: -1-\text{ceil}(√7)+3^4 $
>  $78: 1*\text{ceil}(√7)+3^4$
>  $79: 1-\text{ceil}(√7)+3^4$
>  $80: -1^7+3^4$
>  $81: \text{floor}(1/7)+3^4$
>  $82: 1^7+3^4$
>  $83: -1+7*3*4$
>  $84: 1*7*3*4$
>  $85: 1+7*3*4 $
>  $86: \text{floor}(173/√4)$
>  $87: -1+7*3^4$
>  $88: 1*7+3^4$
>  $89: 1+7+3^4$
>  $90: 1*\text{ceil}(√7*34)$
>  $91: 1+\text{ceil}(√7*34)$
>  $92: \text{floor}(√((-1+7)!*3*4))$
>  $93: \text{ceil}(√((-1+7)!*3*4))$
>  $94: \text{floor}((1+7+√3)^{√4})$
>  $95: \text{ceil}((1+7+√3)^{√4})$
>  $96: \text{floor}(√(1+7)*34)$
>  $97: \text{ceil}(√(1+7)*34)$
>  $98: 1*\text{ceil}(√(7! *√3) )+4$
>  $99: -1+(7+3)^{√4}$
>  $100:1*(7+3)^{√4}$

Comment: As far as I understand the OP, the rules do not allow negative numbers and -1 would not be allowed as this is not a subtraction.

Comment: @lukas.j Negative numbers are allowed.

Comment: Then I think your question should have mentioned negation resp. the unary minus. Basically you have a contradiction in your question because now with allowing the unary minus, you have 8 digits to chose of, whereby 1 or -1 must be used first, then 7 or -7, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt if a binary operator is needed at all, some solutions

> 41 = ⌊√1734⌋
> 42 = ⌈√1734⌉
>
> 35 = ⌊√√√√√41!⌋  i.e.  ⌊√√√√√⌊√1734⌋!⌋
> 36 = ⌈√√√√√41!⌉
> 39 = ⌊√√√√√42!⌋
> 40 = ⌈√√√√√42!⌉
>
> 28 =  ⌊√√√√√39!⌋
> 29 =  ⌈√√√√√39!⌉
> 31 =  ⌊√√√√√40!⌋
> 32 =  ⌊√√√√√40!⌋
> 17 =  ⌊√√√√√35!⌋
> 18 =  ⌈√√√√√35!⌉
> 19 =  ⌊√√√√√36!⌋
> 20 =  ⌈√√√√√36!⌉
>
> 69 =  ⌊√√√√28!⌋
> 70 =  ⌈√√√√28!⌉
> 8 =  ⌊√√√√√28!⌋
> 9 =  ⌈√√√√√28!⌉
> 85 =  ⌊√√√√29!⌋
> 86 =  ⌈√√√√29!⌉
> 10 =  ⌈√√√√√29!⌉
> 11 =  ⌊√√√√√31!⌋
> 12 =  ⌈√√√√√31!⌉
> 13 =  ⌈√√√√√32!⌉
> 65 =  ⌊√√√17!⌋
> 66 =  ⌈√√√17!⌉
> 94 =  ⌊√√√18!⌋
> 95 =  ⌈√√√18!⌉
> 14 =  ⌊√√√√20!⌋
> 15 =  ⌈√√√√20!⌉
>
> 33 =  ⌈√√√15!⌉
> 23 =  ⌊√√√14!⌋
> 24 =  ⌈√√√14!⌉
> 16 =  ⌊√√√13!⌋
> 17 =  ⌈√√√13!⌉
> 79 =  ⌊√√11!⌋
> 80 =  ⌈√√11!⌉
> 43 =  ⌊√√10!⌋
> 44 =  ⌈√√10!⌉
> 25 =  ⌊√√√√23!⌋
> 26 =  ⌈√√√√23!⌉
> 30 =  ⌊√√√√24!⌋

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, each number must be used exactly once, in the order listed.

Here are solutions for a couple dozen numbers:

> 1 = 1 + 7 - 3 - 4

> 2 = 1 + (7 / (3 + 4))

> 7 = 1 + 7 + 3 - 4

> 8 = (1 + 7) ^ (-3 + 4)

> 9 = 1 + 7 - 3 + 4

> 14 = (1 * 7) + 3 + 4

> 15 = 1 + 7 + 3 + 4

> 16 = -1 + (7 * 3) - 4

> 18 = 1 + (7 * 3) - 4

> 19 = (1 * 7) + (3 * 4)

> 20 = 1 + 7 + (3 * 4)

> 26 = 1 + (7 * 3) + 4

> 42 = (-1 + 7) * (3 + 4)

> 49 = 1 * 7 * (3 + 4)

> 56 = (1 + 7) * (3 + 4)

> 64 = -17 + (3 ^ 4)

> 73 = -1 - 7 + (3 ^ 4)

> 75 = 1 - 7 + (3 ^ 4)

> 80 = -(1 ^ 7) + (3 ^ 4)

> 81 = (1 ^ 7) * (3 ^ 4)

> 82 = (1 ^ 7) + (3 ^ 4)

> 87 = -1 + 7 + (3 ^ 4)

> 88 = (1 * 7) + (3 ^ 4)

> 89 = 1 + 7 + (3 ^ 4)

> 96 = (1 + 7) * (3 * 4)

> 98 = 17 + (3 ^ 4)

Comment: Good job finding quite a few important numbers!

Comment: As far as I understand the OP, the rules do not allow negative numbers and -1 would not be allowed as this is not a subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

PARTIAL ANSWER, NOT FINISHED, however I have made quite significant progress.

Ok... Let's have a look.

> 1 : 1 + 7 - 3 - 4
>  2 : 1 x 7 - 3 + 4
>  3 : 1 + 7 - 3 - √4
>  4 : 1 x ⌊(7 / 3)⌋ x √4
>  5 : ⌊(1/7)⌋ + 3 + √4
>  6 : ⌊(1/7)⌋ + 3 x √4
>  7 : ⌊(1/7)⌋ + 3 + 4
>  8 : 1 + 7 - ⌊(3/4)⌋
>  9 : 1 + 7 + ⌈(3/4)⌉
>  10 : ⌊(1 x 7 x 3/√4)⌋
>  11 : 1 + ⌊(7x3/√4)⌋
>  12 : 1 + ⌈(7x3/√4)⌉
>  13 : ⌈(1/7)⌉ + 3 x 4
>  14 : 1 x 7 + 3 + 4
>  15 : 1 + 7 + 3 + 4
>  16 :  -(1 - 7 x 3 + 4)
>  17 : 1 + (7 - 3) x 4
>  18 : -(1 - (7 + 3 x 4))
>  19 : 1 x (7 + 3 x 4)
>  20 : 1 + 7 + 3 x 4
>  21 : 1 - 7 + 3 + 4!
>  22 : -1 - 7 + 3! + 4!
>  23 : 1 + 7 + 3! + 4!
>  24 : -1 + 7 x 3 + 4
>  25 : 1 x 7 x 3 + 4
>  26 : 1 + 7 - 3! + 4!
>  27 : ⌊1/7⌋ + 3 + 4!
>  28 : ⌈1/7⌉ + 3 + 4!
>  29 : 17 + 3 x 4
>  30 : 1^7 x 3! + 4!
>  31 : ⌊(⌈√17⌉^3/4)⌋
>  32 : ⌊√17⌋^3/√4
>  33 : -1 + 7 + 3 + 4! (thank you wimi)
>  34 : -1 + (7!/3!)/4!
>  35 : 1 x (7!/3!)/4!
>  36 : 1 + (7!/3!)/4!
>  37 : ⌈1/7⌉ + √(3!^4)
>  38 : 1 + 7 + 3! + 4!
>  39 : -1 + (7 + 3) x 4 (thank you wimi)
>  40 : (1 x 7 + 3) × 4 (thank you wimi)
>  41 : ⌊√1734⌋
>  42 : (-1 + 7) x (3 + 4)
>  43 : ⌊173/4⌋
>  44 : ⌈173/4⌉
>  45 : -1 + 7 x (3!) + 4
>  46 : 1 x 7 x (3!) + 4
>  47 : 17 x 3 - 4
>  48 : -1 + 7 ^ ⌊(√(3+4))⌊
>  49 : 1 x 7 x (3 + 4)
>  50 : 1 + 7 ^ ⌊(√(3+4))⌋
>  51 : 17 + 34
>  52 : ⌊√173⌋ x 4
>  53 : 17 + √(3!^4)
>  54 : (1 + ⌊√√7!⌋) x 3 x √4
>  55 : 17 x 3 + 4
>  56 : (1 + 7) x (3 + 4)
>  57 :
>  58 :
>  59 : -1 + ⌊√(7)⌋ x (3!+4!)
>  60 : ⌊√(1+7)⌋ x (3!+4!)
>  61 : 1+ ⌊√(7)⌋ x (3!+4!)
>  62 : ⌊(⌈√17⌉^3/√4)⌋
>  63 : ⌈(⌈√17⌉^3/√4)⌉
>  64 :  -17 + (3 ^ 4)
>  65 :
>  66 :
>  67 :
>  68 : -1 + 73 - 4
>  69 : 1 x 73 - 4
>  70 : 1 + 73 - 4
>  71 :
>  72 :
>  73 : -1 + (-7 + 3 ^4)
>  74 : 1 x (-7 + 3 ^ 4)
>  75 : 1 + (-7 + 3 ^4)
>  76 : -1 + 73 + 4
>  77 : 1 x (73 + 4)
>  78 : 1 + 73 + 4
>  79 : 1 x 7 + 3! x 4!
>  80 : -(1 ^ 7) + (3 ^ 4)
>  81 : (1 ^ 7) x (3 ^ 4)
>  82 : (1 ^ 7) + (3 ^ 4)
>  83 : 1 + ⌊√7!⌋ + 3 x 4
>  84 : -1 + ⌊7^3/4⌋
>  85 : 1 x ⌊7^3/4⌋
>  86 : 1 + ⌊7^3/4⌋
>  87 : -1 + 7 + (3 ^ 4)
>  88 : (1 * 7) + (3 ^ 4)
>  89 : 1 + 7 + (3 ^ 4)
>  90 : ⌈√(1+7)⌉ x (3!+4!)
>  91 : 1 + ⌈√(7)⌉ x (3!+4!)
>  92 : 1 x ⌈√(7!)⌉ − 3 + 4!
>  93 : 1 + ⌈√(7!)⌉ − 3 + 4!
>  94 :
>  95 :
>  96 : (1 + 7) x 3 x 4
>  97 : -1 + ⌈√(7!)⌉ + 3 + 4!
>  98 : 17 + (3 ^ 4 )
>  99 : 1 + ⌈√(7!)⌉ + 3 + 4!
>  100 : 1 ∗ ⌊√(7!)⌋ + 3! + 4!

Comment: (floor(1 - sqrt(sqrt(7)))) + 3 + 4! = 27

Comment: ((floor(1 * sqrt(sqrt(7)))) + 3) * 4! = 96

Comment: I hope the 2 comments up of this one helped.

Comment: You can simplify 42 to 1 + 7 + 34.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Ill add that in.

Comment: floor(sqrt(1734)) = 41

Comment: I've made quite significant progress, and I'll leave it here today for now.

Comment: (17 * 3) + 4 = 55

Comment: Thanks for that, adding it in

Comment: (1 + floor(sqrt(sqrt(7!)))) * (3! * floor(sqrt(sqrt(4))))  = 54

Comment: I wish i could upvote to upvote this post...

Comment: I also made another question!

Comment: Which post? Your question or my answer?

Comment: -1 + 7 + 3 + 4! = 33

Comment: (1 x 7 + 3) × 4 = 40 . Similarly, -1 + (7 + 3) x 4 = 39

Comment: 79 = 1*7 + 3!*4! 
95 = -17 + ceil(sqrt(3!!))*4  
97 = -1*7 + floor(sqrt(3!!))*4 
99 = 1 - ceil(sqrt(7))! + floor(sqrt(3!!)))*4    
100 = (-1^7 + floor(sqrt(3!!)))*4

Comment: $-1+7*(3!)+4=45$ and $1*7*(3!)+4=46$

Comment: $1*⌈√(7!)⌉-3+4!=92$, and modifying this with +1/-1/*1, +3/-3, ⌊⌋ instead of ⌈⌉ you get everything from 91 to 99.

Comment: $1∗⌊√(7!)⌋−3*4=58$, and you can similarly complete everything you need between 65 and 72.

Comment: Finally, $1∗⌊√(7!)⌋+3!+4!=100$

Comment: Thanks! @Evargalo

Comment: How would 94 and 95 work?

Comment: As far as I understand the OP, the rules do not allow negative numbers and -1 would not be allowed as this is not a subtraction.

Comment: @lukas.j I would believe that if that was the case, the OP would have already told me in the comments instead of helping and liking this answer... But then hi! Welcome to PSE!

Comment: @Stevo $1*⌊√(7!)⌋+3!*4=94$ and $1*⌈√(7!)⌉+3!*4=95$

Answer (score 1):

Complete list.

Note that these solutions do not use the unary minus as it is not listed in the OP's list of allowed operators:

> 1: 1 - 7 + 3 + 4
>  2: 1 × 7 - (3 + √4)
>  3: 1 + 7 - (3 + √4)
>  4: 1^7^3 × 4
>  5: 1^7^3 + 4
>  6: 1 - 7 + 3 × 4
>  7: 1 + 7 + 3 - 4
>  8: 1 × 7 - 3 + 4
>  9: 1 + 7 - 3 + 4
>  10: 1 + 7 + 3! - 4
>  11: 1^7 + 3! + 4
>  12: 1^7 × 3 × 4
>  13: 1 + 7 + 3 + √4
>  14: 1 × 7 + 3 + 4
>  15: 1 + 7 + 3 + 4
>  16: (1^7 + 3) × 4
>  17: 1 × 7 × 3 - 4
>  18: 1 + 7 × 3 - 4
>  19: 1 × 7 + 3 × 4
>  20: 1 + 7 + 3 × 4
>  21: 1 - 7 + 3 + 4!
>  22: (1 + 7 + 3) × √4
>  23: 1 × 7 × 3 + √4
>  24: 1 - 7 + 3! + 4!
>  25: 1 × 7 × 3 + 4
>  26: 1 + 7 × 3 + 4
>  27: 1^7 × 3 + 4!
>  28: (1 + 7) × 3 + 4
>  29: 1 + 7 - 3 + 4!
>  30: 1^7 × 3! + 4!
>  31: 1 × 7 + 3! × 4
>  32: 1 + 7 + 3! × 4
>  33: 17 × ⌈ √3 ⌉ - ⌊ √√4 ⌋
>  34: 1 × 7 + 3 + 4!
>  35: 1 + 7 + 3 + 4!
>  36: 1 + 7! / 3! / 4!
>  37: 1 × 7 + 3! + 4!
>  38: 1 × 7 × 3! - 4
>  39: 1 + 7 × 3! + 4
>  40: 1 × (7 + 3) × 4
>  41: 1 + (7 + 3) × 4
>  42: 1 × 7 × 3 × √4
>  43: 1 + 7 × 3 × √4
>  44: (1 + 7 + 3) × 4
>  45: 1 × 7 × 3 + 4!
>  46: 1 + 7 × 3 + 4!
>  47: 1 + 7 × 3! + 4
>  48: (1 + 7) × 3 × √4
>  49: 1 × 7 × (3 + 4)
>  50: 1 + 7 × (3 + 4)
>  51: 17 + 34
>  52: 1 × (7 + 3!) × 4
>  53: 1 + (7 + 3!) × 4
>  54: ⌈ (1 + 7 + 3) × √4! ⌉
>  55: 17 × 3 + 4
>  56: (1 + 7) × (3 + 4)
>  57: 1 + 7 × (3! + √4)
>  58: 17 × ⌈ √3 ⌉ + 4!
>  59: 1 × 7 + ⌊ 3!^√√4! ⌋
>  60: (1 + 7 - 3)! / √4
>  61: 1 + ⌈ 7^√3 ⌉ + ⌊ √√√√4!! ⌋
>  62: 1 + ⌈ 7^√3 ⌉ + ⌈ √√√√4!! ⌉
>  63: 1 × 7 × 3^√4
>  64: 1 + 7 × 3^√4
>  65: 17 × ⌈ √3 ⌉ + ⌈ √√√√4!! ⌉
>  66: 1 - 7 + 3 × 4!
>  67: 1 + 7 × 3! + 4!
>  68: 17 × ⌈ √3 ⌉ × √4
>  69: 1 + ⌈ 73 - √4! ⌉
>  70: 1 × 7 × (3! + 4)
>  71: 1 + 7 × (3! + 4)
>  72: (1 + 7) × 3! + 4!
>  73: 1^7 + 3 × 4!
>  74: ⌈ 173 / √√√√√√4!! ⌉
>  75: 1 - 7 + 3^4
>  76: 1 + 73 + √4
>  77: 1 × 73 + 4
>  78: 1 + 73 + 4
>  79: 1 × 7 + 3 × 4!
>  80: 1 + 7 + 3 × 4!
>  81: 1^7 × 3^4
>  82: 1^7 + 3^4
>  83: 1 × ⌈ √7! + 3 × 4 ⌉
>  84: 1 × 7 × 3 × 4
>  85: 1 + 7 × 3 × 4
>  86: ⌊ 173 / √4 ⌋
>  87: ⌈ 173 / √4 ⌉
>  88: 1 × 7 + 3^4
>  89: 1 + 7 + 3^4
>  90: 1 + ⌈ 73^√√√√√4 ⌉
>  91: 1 × ⌈ 73^√√√√√√4! ⌉
>  92: 1 + ⌈ 73^√√√√√√4! ⌉
>  93: ⌊ 17 × √(3! + 4!) ⌋
>  94: ⌈ 17 × √(3! + 4!) ⌉
>  95: 1 × ⌈ √7! + 3! × 4 ⌉
>  96: (1 + 7) × 3 × 4
>  97: 1 + (7 - 3)! × 4
>  98: 1 + 73 + 4!
>  99: 1 + ⌈ √7! ⌉ + 3 + 4!
>  100: 1 × (7 + 3)^√4

Comment: I like that you try to avoid unary-. 83 = sqrt(1+7!) +3*4; 95 = sqrt(1+7!) +3!*4  (no rounding needed)